# Rails seed JSON ignore some attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, seed

I am using the rails JSON gem to quickly seed my database with JSON data.
In my seeds.rb file, i have this method

```
  businessPath = "#{Rails.root}/public/business2.json"
  businesses = JSON.parse(File.read(businessPath))
  businesses.each do |business|
  Business.create!(business)    
end
```

However, the JSON data I was given as a few extra attributes that I do not want this model to Business to have. When I try to seed it as is, I get this error.

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: schools, categories, neighborhoods, longitude, latitude, type
```

Those are the attributes I don't have in my Business model in Rails that are attributes for each business in the JSON file. Is there a way to ignore those attributes before running Business.create?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Hash#slice](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) or [Hash#except](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) that ActiveSupport provides. You can run:

```
businessPath = "#{Rails.root}/public/business2.json"
businesses = JSON.parse(File.read(businessPath))
```

And then you can blacklist the extra attributes

```
businesses.each do |business|
  Business.create!(business.except(:schools, :categories, :neighborhoods, :longitude, :latitude, :type))
end
```

Or whitelist only the attributes you want to keep

```
businesses.each do |business|
  Business.create!(business.slice(:name, :owner, :etc))
end
```